# Add custom *.jar file into build.gradle project dependencies and set up the classpath

Tags: java, gradle

To remove the dependency to `https://artifactory***/***`
we have to move either source code or custom jar files into repository.
There is one custom lib `lcl-core-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar`.

In root project folder was created a directory `externalLibs`
and pasted the file `lcl-core-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar`.
Also in project build.grade in `dependencies` section was added line

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'externalLibs')
```

And in module `base:dynamic-validation` in `dependencies` section was added

```
compile files('externalLibs/lcl-core-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar')
```

After trying to build project I receive

```
/***/base/dynamic-validation/src/main/java/sdk/finance/validation/Data.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    private static final Processor DTO_PROCESSOR = new SimpleProcessor().configure();
                         ^
  symbol:   class Processor
  location: class Data<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Data
```

In Intelij IDEA in the project settings I can add classpath and then import all required classes from the lib and, therefore, use them into my classes. However, went other developer will clone this project they have to do the same manipulations again to compile and build the project.

How to add classpass to external lib into gradle project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependency in `base:dynamic-validation` won't work with a declaration like this: it's a relative path to the current project, not the root.

To be able to use file dependency, just add this code to the repositories list in the main build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/externalLib"
    }
    ...
}
```

https://riptutorial.com/gradle/example/8349/add-a-local-jar-file-dependency